# Curve Fitting Atmospheric Density

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I'm trying to make some code to predict the performance of a sounding rocket I want to build.  To do this, I need the atmospheric density at any point in the flight for the time-step simulation I made.

I got my atmospheric density in slug/ft^3 from https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/standard-atmosphere-d_604.html and put all that data in this python script, under the assumption that the function that would best describe this data would be a negative exponential.

```
from scipy import optimize

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def fxn(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c

altitudes = np.array([0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000,150000,200000,250000])

density1 = np.array([23.8,20.48,17.56,14.96,12.67,10.66,8.91,7.38,5.87,4.62,3.64,2.26,1.39,.86,.56,.33,.037,.0053,.00065])

altitudeLinSpace = np.linspace(0,500000,500000)

#Popt returns a array containing constants a,b,c... etc for function 'fxn'
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fxn, altitudes, density1, p0=(1, 1e-6, 1))

print(popt)


#Plots data
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim((0,25))
plt.plot(altitudes, density1)
plt.plot(altitudeLinSpace, fxn(altitudeLinSpace, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]))
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this graph when I plot the solution ( Altitude ft (x), density in slug/ft^3 * 10^-4 (y)):
[image: Altitude(x), density in slug/ft^3 * 10^-4 (y)]

The orange curve is what python found as a solution, blue is the plot of the data I used to curve fit.  Because of the poor fit, my guess is that the data is actually not a negative exponential, but I'm not really sure how to determine the kind of function this might be...

I'm not looking for perfect, but using a polynomial is a less than ideal solution here as the 'wiggles' give too much error at higher altitudes.

Any suggestions on how I could fit this data better would be greatly appreciated!

Solution from Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3009560/curve-fitting-atmosphere

Comment: Surely the exponential is negative as the y’s are reducing as x’s increase?

Comment: @solarMike, well that was my first thought, but its clearly more complex than that...  maybe 1/x should be in there somewhere?

Comment: So, put the data in excel and get the equation of the line it suggests...

Comment: @solarMike, Every option on Excel fits the data terribly  Best fit is 5th order polynomial which is not good enough for the precision I need.  First thing I did when I got this data was put it into excel.

Comment: No mention of that in your question, if you don’t say, how can we guess???

Comment: The most simple model is indeed exponential, but the real atmosphere is more complex, with density varying a lot with temperature (besides pressure), and temperature varying with altitude in a manner that is... uh, a subject of advanced studies. Various layers of atmosphere differing in properties *a lot*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are fitting results with the equation shown.

[image: Plot with fitting results]

Any greater accuracy requires a model beyond this very crude, semi-empirical fit. Pay attention to the confidence limits (1$\sigma$ values). To first order, they can be propagated through your prediction equation using linear uncertainty analysis. This can help you decide whether extra effort is needed to be more accurate, for example by splitting the pressure regions and/or by getting higher resolution data (more data points in the full or desired range).

Comment: The solution I went for under advise from the Math stack exchange is very similar to your fit, except -Bt^n is the sumation of multiple -B_i t^n _i terms. For better precision.  Thanks for this solution!

Comment: @WhisperingShiba Please post the solution that you obtained and/or a link to the Math stack exchange where you referenced it.

Comment: The multiple terms probably reflect the varying species that make up the atmosphere.

Comment: @PhilSweet The multiple terms are just empirical "stick your thumb up and eyeball it" parameters. The greater emphasis here is to be placed on non-linear regression to obtain both the empirical fit parameters **and their confidence limits**. When the OP is doing any serious predication, it can and should include a proper handling of the uncertainties that are noted here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a curve fit, why not just do an interpolation of the data. Cubic spline interpolation should give sufficient precision. Look at scipy.interpolate

Answer (score 2):

The density varies exponentially - but at rate dependent not just on altitude but also temperature.

[image]
[source](https://scied.ucar.edu/atmosphere-layers)

[image]
[source](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap2.html)

If you want a more precise fit, you'll have to split it up into atmospheric layers:

- Troposphere: 0 to 12 km (0 to 7 miles)
- Stratosphere: 12 to 50 km (7 to 31 miles)
- Mesosphere: 50 to 80 km (31 to 50 miles)
- Thermosphere: 80 to 700 km (50 to 440 miles)
- Exosphere: 700 to 10,000 km (440 to 6,200 miles)

and fit the exponent into each of these - possibly introducing additional thresholds for stratosphere (at 20km and 35km) - a spline created of exponential curves. Trying to find a single simple function to fit reality with this sort of complexity is a misguided attempt.

Comment: The choice also depends on the desired accuracy versus the data precision. The spread in the distances in the data file may not have enough resolution to allow the fit to be done over multiple layers.  In essence, fitting two data points to an exponential is then misguided. Alternatively, the desire for a quick-and-dirty analytical equation over the entire range that has clear definitions of the confidence limits may overrule the need to do layer-by-layer fitting for accuracy. This latter approach is certainly misguided when the confidence limits are subsequently ignored.

Comment: Nice graphic. Can you reference the URL where you got it. Also, is there an equivalent that shows pressure?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer: Edited these in. It's pretty hard to find graphs that extend past ~80-100km with log scale, which is essential for the graph to be of actual use. If you find one, let me know.